# generating random matrices in python

Tags: python, matrix, numerical-methods

In the following code I have implemented Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting for a general square linear system Ax=b. I have tested my code and it produced the right output. However now I am trying to do the following but I am not quite sure how to code it, looking for some help with this!

**I want to test my implementation by solving Ax=b where A is a random 100x100 matrix and b is a random 100x1 vector.**

In my code I have put in the matrices

```
A = np.array([[3.,2.,-4.],[2.,3.,3.],[5.,-3.,1.]])

b =  np.array([[3.],[15.],[14.]])
```

and gotten the following correct output:

```
[3. 1. 2.]
[3. 1. 2.]
```

**but now how do I change it to generate the random matrices?**

here is my code below:

```
import numpy as np
def GEPP(A, b, doPricing = True):
    '''
    Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting.
    input: A is an n x n numpy matrix
           b is an n x 1 numpy array
    output: x is the solution of Ax=b 
        with the entries permuted in 
        accordance with the pivoting 
        done by the algorithm
    post-condition: A and b have been modified.
    '''
    n = len(A)
    if b.size != n:

        raise ValueError("Invalid argument: incompatible sizes between"+

                     "A & b.", b.size, n)

    # k represents the current pivot row. Since GE traverses the matrix in the 

    # upper right triangle, we also use k for indicating the k-th diagonal 

    # column index.

    # Elimination

    for k in range(n-1):

        if doPricing:

            # Pivot

            maxindex = abs(A[k:,k]).argmax() + k

            if A[maxindex, k] == 0:


                raise ValueError("Matrix is singular.")

            # Swap

            if maxindex != k:

                A[[k,maxindex]] = A[[maxindex, k]]

                b[[k,maxindex]] = b[[maxindex, k]]

        else:

            if A[k, k] == 0:

                raise ValueError("Pivot element is zero. Try setting doPricing to True.")

       #Eliminate

       for row in range(k+1, n):

           multiplier = A[row,k]/A[k,k]

           A[row, k:] = A[row, k:] - multiplier*A[k, k:]

           b[row] = b[row] - multiplier*b[k]

    # Back Substitution

    x = np.zeros(n)

    for k in range(n-1, -1, -1):

        x[k] = (b[k] - np.dot(A[k,k+1:],x[k+1:]))/A[k,k]

    return x



if __name__ == "__main__":

    A = np.array([[3.,2.,-4.],[2.,3.,3.],[5.,-3.,1.]])

    b =  np.array([[3.],[15.],[14.]])

    print (GEPP(np.copy(A), np.copy(b), doPricing = False))

    print (GEPP(A,b))
```

Answer (score 3):

You're already using numpy. Have you considered `np.random.rand`?

`np.random.rand(m, n)` will get you a random matrix with values in [0, 1). You can further process it by multiplying random values or rounding.

EDIT: Something like this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = np.round(np.random.rand(100, 100)*10)
    b =  np.round(np.random.rand(100)*10)
    print (GEPP(np.copy(A), np.copy(b), doPricing = False))
    print (GEPP(A,b))
```

Comment: how can I put this into my code? where should it go?

Comment: you can use it to generate your `A` and `b`, then pass them into your function as normal. Instead of hardcoding the `A` and `b`

Comment: Rohan's answer is better, you don't have to round to int

Comment: I am getting some errors when I put his in, it says the pivot is 0

Comment: maybe the randomly generated A is not full rank? i.e. not all columns are independent

does it work with smaller sizes than 100? Try 4 for instance, and try it multiple times

Comment: your code works, is there a problem with the output your produces compared to Rohan's?

Comment: no, nothing like that. I just prefer his since it generates random integers, whereas mine generates random numbers in [0,1) and I have to further transform them to integers. Which takes another step. His is just a tad more efficient

Comment: could you edit yours to make them generate random intergers?

Comment: that's what the `np.round()` and multiplying by 10 is for. it does generate integers as you should be able to see by printing `A` and `b`

Answer (score 2):

So I would use [np.random.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) for this.

```
numpy.random.randint(low, high=None, size=None, dtype='l')
```

which outputs a size-shaped array of random integers from the appropriate distribution, or a single such random int if size not provided.

`low` is the lower bound of the ints you want in your range

`high` is one greater than the upper bound in your desired range

`size` is the dimensions of your output array

`dtype` is the dtype of the result

so if I was you I would write

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 11, (100, 100))
b = np.random.randint(0, 11, 100)
```

Comment: it says the pivot is 0

Comment: it means that it produced a linearly dependent matrix and it can't solve it because A has no inverse. A linearly dependent matrix has no inverse

Comment: you need to randomly generate a linearly independent matrix

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could create the desired matrices with ones and then iterate over them, setting each value to `random.randint(0,100)` for example.

Empty matrix with ones is:

```
one_array = np.ones((100, 100))
```

EDIT:

like:

```
for x in one_array.shape[0]:
    for y in one_array.shape[1]:
        one_array[x][y] = random.randint(0, 100)
```

Comment: @user123 You can create a function. Or use unit tests. The function would for example repeat 100 times and produce random input for your program. Then you can call your Programm. You just have to think about how you want to verify the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = np.random.normal(size=(100,100))
b = np.random.normal(size=(100,1))
x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
assert max(abs(A@x - b)) < 1e-12
```

Clearly, you can use different distributions than `normal`, like `uniform`.

Comment: where should I put this into my program?

Comment: Whereever you set your matrix `A` and vector `b`.

Comment: I put it in for a and b but it gave me huge matrices for answers

Comment: Was the result 100x1?  Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: I believe I am getting 2 matrices

Comment: yes you are correct I forgot to take that out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy's native rand function:

```
np.random.rand()
```

In your code just define A and b as:

```
A = np.random.rand(100, 100)
b = np.random.rand(100)
```

This will generate 100x100 matrix and 100x1 vector (both numpy arrays) filled with random values between 0 and 1.

See the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) for this function to learn more.

Comment: and then how could I get the proper output when I call to print?

Comment: You can print it the same way you printed the 3x1 matrix example since it is the same data type as the one generated by np.random.rand()

Comment: okay so all I need to do is replace my a and b with the a and b you have above?

Comment: why random values between 0 and 1? why not greater then 1?

Comment: Because the function gives you a uniform distribution between 0 and 1 by default. If you want to specify your own range use numpy.random.radint() from the answer by Rohan D'Souza.